# Select Element using a Class that has multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ajax call that gets data from a query, I am adding the mark up to the page to display the results like so:

```
 $('.address-results').append("<div class='address-result'><h5 class='bold-blue'>" + po.CompanyName + "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign address-icon'></span></h5><span>" + po.Street + "</span><br/><span>" + po.Town + "</span><br/><span>" + po.County + "</span><br/><span>" + po.Postcode + "</span><br /><button class='btn btn-sm btn-member' id = "+ po.Id+">Enquire</button></div>")
```

When the results are rendered (10) I want to select the button I have generated, which has a `GUID` as the `ID` the result all brings back the same classes for the button, I want to target the button which is clicked and then get the ID so I can do another query. I can't seem to get the button it just keeps reloading the page, I wondered if there were to many buttons with the same class and it didn't know which button? I have looked in the console and the elements are all there. This is the jQuery I am using to try and target the buttons, but I only want the one I select.

```
$('.btn-member').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('hi');
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(id);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

As you are adding HTML dynamically, You need to use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach.

i.e.

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Example

```
$('.address-results').on('click', ".btn-member", function(){
    //Your code
});
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container.

Additionally, You should use custom `data-` prefixed HTML attributes. Which can be fetched using [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
//Event Binding
$('.address-results').on('click', ".btn-member", function(){
    alert($(this).data('id'))
});

//Append element
$('.address-results').append("<button class='btn-member' data-id='"+ po.Id+"'>Enquire</button>")
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Event Binding
  $('.address-results').on('click', ".btn-member", function() {
    alert($(this).data('id'))
  });

  //Append element
  $('.address-results').append("<button class='btn-member' data-id='" + 12345 + "'>Enquire</button>")

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='address-results'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Much appreciated for the effort.